# Django Vote System - django-secretballot and django-vote both are faulty for me, should I write voting system myself?

Tags: python, django, django-models

I would like to ask you for your help. I want to have some simple voting system on my django app. I googled it and I found two systems and some posts about not reinventing wheel and I am all for that :P

First I tried to go with django-vote, it was updated two years ago. I setup it, added into apps, models, created function for it with user_id but I got error with "LazyObject". user_id from django-vote was expecting int, and not actual user name like it is in my app.

So I went with django-secretballot next. But soon after adding it into middleware and apps I am getting error while I want to migrate:

```
ImportError: cannot import name 'python_2_unicode_compatible' from 'django.utils.encoding'
```

And right now I am lost. Should I try to ask for help and try to fix any of those two applications or I should look for another one or try to write it myself since I need only basic functions? Which approach would be better?

Thanks and Cheers!

@Edit:

I am sorry, I didn't phrased my question in a good way. I wanted to ask if my thought process is correct. I assumed that both of those errorw ith these django packages are because one of them is from 2 years ago and second one from 3 years ago and that is why I have problem with them. Not because of my implementation. That was first part of my question.

And second one, was about if I should look for another python package, try to fix one of mentioned before somehow (if it is "doable" and relatively easy?) or just write some simple system myself ?

Sorry for first "iteration" of my question.

Comment: That's not a bad question in itself, but it's definitly not on topic here as there's no clear _technical_ answer to this. Only you can decide which approach would be the best for your current use case, depending on your specs and constraints and the amount of work required to fix / customize one of those third-part apps vs writing your own from scratch. Just note that while "reinventing the wheel" is indeed usually a bad idea, this only applies to non-trivial problems.

Comment: Sorry, you are right. I edited my first post with some clarification about my question. Please look at it if you can. Thanks